# WSO2 Integration Studio 8.0.1 Connectors error while Importing a project

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

In WSO2 Integration studio while importing a project I get a connectors error but in the API level only the Gmail connector is used but I add the connector in the project and as well as in the server but the project import error is still exist what should I do to sort this kind of error.

**Note:** so many times restarted the integration studio nothing worked!
[image: Studio Error]
[image: Server Connector]

Comment: Can you post the connectors error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the connector to the ESB Project as shown below? Also, it's best to pack the connector in the Capp itself by creating a [Connector Exporter project](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/develop/creating-artifacts/adding-connectors/#packaging-connectors).

[image]

Comment: yes I added the connector in the Add or Remove Connector/Module option but the connector error still exist.